# npx create-next-app@latest | npm ERR! canceled

Tags: nodejs, npm, next.js, nextjs13

Hola estoy intentando crear una nueva aplicación con next js, pero al momento de ejecutar:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

Me apararecen los siguientes mensajes:

```
npm ERR! canceled

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.npm/_logs/2023-10-05T18_45_45_883Z-debug-0.log
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el archivo que mencionar la terminal aparece lo siguiente:

```
0 verbose cli /Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/bin/node /Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.8.0
2 info using node@v20.5.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/Desktop/Prueba/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 6ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm exec create-next-app@latest
22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-next-app@latest"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 5ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.npm/_logs/2023-10-05T18_45_45_883Z-
26 verbose logfile /Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.npm/_logs/2023-10-05T18_45_45_883Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 4ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-next-app 521ms (cache revalidated)
35 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
36 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
37 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
38 timing command:exec Completed in 5514ms
39 verbose stack Error: canceled
39 verbose stack     at exec (/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js:268:19)
39 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
39 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5)
40 verbose cwd /Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/Desktop/Prueba
41 verbose Darwin 23.0.0
42 verbose node v20.5.0
43 verbose npm  v9.8.0
44 error canceled
45 verbose exit 1
46 timing npm Completed in 5632ms
47 verbose code 1
48 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/brandonurielgarciaramos/.npm/_logs/2023-10-05T18_45_45_883Z-debug-0.log
```

He utilizado las versiones 18 y 20 de node, ambas me dan el mismo error.

La version de npm es 9.8.0.

De antemano muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

He intentano cambiar las versiones de node y tambien intente instalar una version especifica de nextjs.